# Designing table relationships help

Tags: mysql, database-design

I would like some input on the best way to design this database relationship. We have a **project** entity, which has two **areas** as related entities. In the UI the main entity is the project, and then we have two tabs - one for each area. Both areas are of the same entity type, so I currently have this relationship modeled as a one-to-many relationship between project and area. We don't think we will ever need more than those two areas per project, and an area has a flag that signifies which type of area it is (the two areas have different types).

There is something bugging me about this design. When I need to get one of the areas for a project, I have to get the list of areas related to the project and filter on the flag. There will only ever be one area per type per project.

I have considered if I could reverse the relation, so the project references the two areas via two one-to-one relationships, but since both areas are of the same entity type I am not sure how to do that (as they cannot both have the same shared primary key as the project).

Can someone come up with a better design? - or do you think the current one-to-many is good enough?

We are using MySQL 8.
Extra bonus if the solution would work well with Entity Framework Core.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: *an area has a flag that signifies which type of area it is (the two areas have different types).* Does this flag is an attribute of the area or of the link between area and project? Or it doesn't matter in practice but you decide to make it an attribute of (what?).

Comment: Does the same instance of area entity joined to some project may be joined to another project (at the same time or instead of)? Does the flag of the instance of area may be changed (theoretically, not in practice)?

Comment: @Akina good questions - thanks! The same instance of an area may not be joined to any other project, and it would not make sense to replace an area with another one (in the business domain). The flag on an area would not change either - once the area is created, it would remain that type of area. The area type could be modeled in the relation between the area and the project, if I had two relations from the project to the respective areas. Does that answer your questions?

Comment: If so I'd (in general) prefer to consider these two different types of area as two different entities (and two separate tables, two reference fields for project entity, etc.). But it depends on the facts: 1) does the "We don't think we will ever need more than those two areas per project" is "we think only" or "third area per project is impossible in theory, at least now"; 2) does there exists some case(s) when the data of these areas must be processed in complex regardless of area type.

Comment: Ok, that is interesting - thanks! We kept the areas as the same entity type as most of the UI and APIs etc., for working inside an area, could then be completely reused between the area types. For now, I don't think it is worth it for us to split them up into two different entities, as we would make it harder to maintain